# CMake: Installing multiple build artifacts properly

Tags: cmake

I use `ADD_CUSTOM_TARGET` to build make project which produces dozens of static libraries. Then I want to `install` it properly for other projects to be able to consume these build results. How exactly I supposed to do that?

As I understand I have to create targets for each library, and then create `mylib-config.cmake` referencing these targets.
After looking here and there I came up with something like this

```
#... here comes ADD_CUSTOM_TARGET to build my Makefile project...
FILE(WRITE "share/dpdk-config.cmake" "include(CMakeFindDependencyMacro)\n")
FILE(GLOB LIBS ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/build/lib/*.a)
FOREACH (LIB_FILE_NAME ${LIBS})
    GET_FILENAME_COMPONENT(LIB_NAME ${LIB_FILE_NAME} NAME_WE)
    SET(TARGET_NAME ${LIB_NAME}_target)
    ADD_CUSTOM_TARGET(${TARGET_NAME} DEPENDS ${LIB})
    ADD_LIBRARY(${LIB_NAME} STATIC IMPORTED GLOBAL)
    ADD_DEPENDENCIES(${LIB_NAME} ${TARGET_NAME})
    SET_TARGET_PROPERTIES(${LIB_NAME}
                          PROPERTIES
                          IMPORTED_LOCATION ${LIB_FILE_NAME}
                          INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE}/include
                          )
    INSTALL(TARGETS ${LIB_NAME}
            EXPORT ${TARGET_NAME}
            ARCHIVE DESTINATION ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/build/lib
            )

    INSTALL(
            EXPORT ${TARGET_NAME}
            DESTINATION share/dpdk
    )
    FILE(APPEND "share/dpdk-config.cmake" "include(share/dpdk/${TARGET_NAME}.cmake)\n")

    #    MESSAGE(STATUS "Library file: ${LIB_FILE_NAME}")
    #    MESSAGE(STATUS "Library: ${LIB_NAME}")
    #    MESSAGE(STATUS "Library target: ${TARGET_NAME}")
ENDFOREACH ()

INSTALL(DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/build/lib
        DESTINATION ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE}/)

INSTALL(DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/build/include
        DESTINATION ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE}/)
```

First, I'm not sure it is the right way to do it, second, it doesnt work.
Any help will be appreciated

EDIT:
Ok, this approach woulnt work since the imported library cannot be exported. See [CMake issue #14311](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/issues/14311)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, actually my bet was close enough. `INSTALL` will not work, but you can use `ConfigXXX.cmake` to gather all necessary information, create exported libraries, add necessary properties and voila. As example one can pickup Intel's TBB, it has similar problem which they solve by above approach. I simply created a function based on their script

```
FUNCTION(SET_LIBRARY_TARGET LIB_FILE_NAME INCLUDE_DIR ISDEBUG)
    SET(POSTFIX "_release")
    IF (${ISDEBUG})
        SET(POSTFIX "_debug")
    ENDIF ()

    GET_FILENAME_COMPONENT(LIB_NAME ${LIB_FILE_NAME} NAME_WE)

    STRING(REPLACE "librte_" "" LIB_NAME "${LIB_NAME}")
    STRING(REPLACE "libdpdk" "dpdk" LIB_NAME "${LIB_NAME}")
    STRING(APPEND LIB_NAME "${POSTFIX}")

    ADD_LIBRARY(DPDK::${LIB_NAME} STATIC IMPORTED)
    SET_TARGET_PROPERTIES(DPDK::${LIB_NAME} PROPERTIES INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES "${INCLUDE_DIR}")

    IF (${ISDEBUG})
        SET_PROPERTY(TARGET DPDK::${LIB_NAME} APPEND PROPERTY IMPORTED_LOCATION_DEBUG "${LIB_FILE_NAME}")
        SET_PROPERTY(TARGET DPDK::${LIB_NAME} APPEND PROPERTY IMPORTED_CONFIGURATIONS DEBUG)
    ELSE ()
        SET_PROPERTY(TARGET DPDK::${LIB_NAME} APPEND PROPERTY IMPORTED_LOCATION_RELEASE "${LIB_FILE_NAME}")
        SET_PROPERTY(TARGET DPDK::${LIB_NAME} APPEND PROPERTY IMPORTED_CONFIGURATIONS RELEASE)
    ENDIF ()

    SET(DPDK_${LIB_NAME}_FOUND 1)
ENDFUNCTION()
```

I guess it can be more elegant than that, be my guest to improve it

EDIT001:
More clean and compact version

```
FUNCTION(SET_LIBRARY_TARGET NAMESPACE LIB_NAME DEBUG_LIB_FILE_NAME RELEASE_LIB_FILE_NAME INCLUDE_DIR)
    ADD_LIBRARY(${NAMESPACE}::${LIB_NAME} STATIC IMPORTED)
    SET_TARGET_PROPERTIES(${NAMESPACE}::${LIB_NAME} PROPERTIES
                          IMPORTED_CONFIGURATIONS "RELEASE;DEBUG"
                          IMPORTED_LOCATION_RELEASE "${RELEASE_LIB_FILE_NAME}"
                          IMPORTED_LOCATION_DEBUG "${DEBUG_LIB_FILE_NAME}"
                          INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES "${INCLUDE_DIR}"
                          )
    SET(${NAMESPACE}_${LIB_NAME}_FOUND 1)
ENDFUNCTION()
```